# I had answered a question yesterday. Today it shows deleted for purposes. Why?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I had answered a question of Normal Clock vs Broken Clock [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718030/deleted-for-purposes/1718472#1718472)

Today it shows that it has been deleted for purposes. What does it mean? The question was good and had 4 (now 2) upvotes so there is a low chance that it was closed down. I want to ask what really had happened?

Is it possible to bring back the question?

Comment: The original poster deleted the question and the answer became collateral damage. I just undeleted the thread and rolled back the question to the latest readable form.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks.

Comment: @Jyrki: It's weird, because it shouldn't be possible to delete a thread with upvoted answers. If the OP says that the answer had 4 upvotes it shouldn't have been possible for this to happen.

Comment: @Asaf yes, if, but they don't.

Comment: @Asaf the *question* [had](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/326720/hey012983?tab=reputation) 4 upvotes but not the answer.

Comment: @Surb: Gotcha. Thanks!